# How to do unit test on a method that has StreamReader and Database access

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing

I have never done unit tests before. I'd like to learn how to do it. I'd like to use Visual Studio unit test and moq.

My project is transferring data from interbase to SQL Server. Firstly, I extract data from interbase into a plain text file. The layout is FieldName + some spaces up to 32 char length + field value. Then, I write a method that reads the text file line by line; once it reaches the next record, it inserts the current record into SQL Server.

So it involves in stream reader and SQL database insertion. For the stream reader, I read some post on the Internet and I pass the Stream reader as the method's parameter; but the SQL Server part, I have no idea how to simplify my method so that it can be tested.

I really need your help.

```
public partial class TableTransfer
{
    #region declare vars
    public string FirstFldName = "";
    public string ErrorMsg = "";
    public List<MemoBlobTrio> MemoBlobs = null;
    public string SqlServerTableName = "";
    #endregion

    public bool DoTransfer(System.IO.StreamReader sr, Func<TransferShare, string, string, bool> TransferTable)
    {
        #region declare var
        bool DoInsert = true;
        TransferShare transferShare = null;
        string line = string.Empty;
        string blobLines = string.Empty;
        string fldName = string.Empty;
        string value = string.Empty;
        bool Is1stLine = true;
        bool isMemoFld = false;
        MemoBlobTrio memoBlobTrio = null;
        int idx = 0;
        #endregion

        try
        {
            using(sr)
            {
                transferShare = new TransferShare();
                ConnectSQLServer(transferShare);
                transferShare.StartInsert(SqlServerTableName);
                bool readNext = true;
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (readNext)
                            line = sr.ReadLine();

                        if ((line != null) && (line.Trim() != ""))
                        {
                            fldName = line.Length > 30 ? line.Substring(0, 31).TrimEnd() : "";

                            Is1stLine = fldName == FirstFldName;
                            if (Is1stLine)
                            {
                                if (DoInsert)
                                    EndInsert(transferShare, line);
                                else
                                    transferShare.ClearSQL();
                                DoInsert = true;
                            }

                            idx = 0;
                            isMemoFld = false;
                            while (idx < MemoBlobs.Count)
                            {
                                if (fldName == (MemoBlobs[idx] as MemoBlobTrio).fbFldName)
                                {
                                    memoBlobTrio = MemoBlobs[idx] as MemoBlobTrio;
                                    line = InsertMemoBlob(transferShare, sr, memoBlobTrio.ssFldName, fldName, memoBlobTrio.fbNextFldName);
                                    readNext = false;
                                    isMemoFld = true;
                                }
                                idx++;
                            }

                            if (!isMemoFld)
                            {
                                if (line.Length > 31)
                                    value = line.Remove(0, 31);
                                else
                                    value = "";
                                if (!TransferTable(transferShare, fldName, value))
                                    DoInsert = false;
                                readNext = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        HandleError(err, line);
                    }

                } while (line != null);
                if (DoInsert)
                    EndInsert(transferShare, line);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            transferShare.SQLConn.Dispose();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void ConnectSQLServer(TransferShare transferShare)
    {
        TransferShare.SQLServerConnStr = "Data Source=" + Environment.MachineName + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True";
        transferShare.SQLConn.ConnectionString = TransferShare.SQLServerConnStr;
        transferShare.SQLConn.Open();
    }
}

public class TransferShare
{
    public void StartInsert(string TableName)
    {
        tableName = TableName;
    }

    public void EndInsert(TransferShare transferShare, string line)
    {
        SqlCommand Cmd = null;
        try
        {
            sqlInsFld = sqlInsFld.Remove(sqlInsFld.Length - 1);
            sqlInsValue = sqlInsValue.Remove(sqlInsValue.Length - 1);
            sqlInsFld = "Insert into " + tableName + " (" + sqlInsFld + ")";
            sqlInsValue = " Values (" + sqlInsValue + ")";

            Cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlInsFld + sqlInsValue, SQLConn);
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw (new Exception(err.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlInsFld = "";
            sqlInsValue = "";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code needs to be unit testable. Your code is really attempting to do too much in each function.

Comment: This code is too tightly coupled to implementation concerns. That makes it very difficult to test in isolation (unit test). I suggest refactoring said code, applying some SOLID principles. It would greatly improve the test-ability and maintainability of this code.

Comment: I know the code has big problem, but I just have no idea to improve it. Any one can help me?